# how to control WIFI using Raspberry Pi (running Raspbian ) using only C programming

Tags: raspbian, wifi, c

I need to following using Raspberry Pi using only C program (or C++)

- start and stop access point
- connect to a particular access point(with username and password)
- disconnect from access point
- stop and start WiFi

Comment: Are you looking for direct "low-level" APIs for Linux wireless manipulation, or would wrapping existing command line tools in C be sufficient?

You could easily wrap `iw` via `popen()`and `pclose()` in C and it would be a tenth the amount of work.

Answer (score 2):

WPA Supplicant exposes its API via D-Bus interface typically called `fi.epitest.hostap.WPASupplicant` or `fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1`, so you can use that. The advantage of D-Bus is that you can connect to it with debug tools like [`dbus-monitor`](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-monitor.1.html) and test the API before you start writing code.

Here are some useful sources:

- [Documentation](https://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/dbus.html) of WPA Supplicant API
- [D-Bus](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/modules.html) modules reference (I suggest you start by reading about `DBusConnection` and `DBusMessage`).
- A [tutorial](http://www.matthew.ath.cx/misc/dbus) explaining how to connect to D-Bus and send/receive messages in C.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking out for ways to interact with any wpa_supplicant then you can use the control interface exposed by it. wpa_supplicant source itself has two files wpa_ctrl.c and wpa_ctrl.h you can create a library on top of this file, the following link will provide the necessary details on how to use the control interface to interact with wpa_supplicant.

[Control interface reference](https://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/ctrl_iface_page.html)

Also wpa_cli itself uses this control interface to talk with wpa_supplicant you can checkout [wpa_cli](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/tree/wpa_supplicant/wpa_cli.c) code for reference as well.